# How to export all URL rewrites in a CSV?

Tags: magento2, database, url-rewrite, csv

I would like to export all my URL rewrites in a CSV, via Magento 2 admin panel I can't do it. I followed this guide below but I didn't find anything native.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html

How could I export it via CSV directly from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL script with the content below.

```
select * from url_rewrite;
```

And run it in that way to generate your CSV file.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magento -pmagento magento < url_rewrites.sql > url_rewrites.csv
```